# JAVA, SWT Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, button, scope, swt, listener

I'm trying to create an i*j number of buttons.

On each button I want to add an mouseUp action, but I get an error.

I tried to create a "Line" class to handle the listener event but failed.

This is what I currently have:

```
protected void createContents() {
    // Connect to prolog engine
    Query.hasSolution("use_module(library(jpl))"); // only because we call e.g. jpl_pl_syntax/1 below
    String t1 = "consult('dots_lines.pl')";
    Query.hasSolution(t1);
    // Build GUI
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");
    shell.setLayout(null);
    txtDotsAndLines = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    txtDotsAndLines.setBounds(175, 10, 86, 21);
    txtDotsAndLines.setText("Dots and lines");
    Button btnStartGame = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnStartGame.setBounds(180, 226, 70, 25);
    btnStartGame.setText("Start Game");
    // TODO: Play with sizes
    int size = 5;
    Line[] lines = new Line[size * (size - 1)];
    // Buttons are line
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            lines[i] = new Line(shell, SWT.NONE);
            lines[i].setBounds(100 + i * 35,54 + j * 13,32,11);
            lines[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
                    lines[i].setEnabled(false);
                    lines[i].setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
                    String t4 = "move([[line(9,10,cpu),line(11,16,cpu),line(16,17,cpu),line(17,22,p1),line(5,6,p1),line(2,3,p1),line(1,2,p1)],cpu],4,X).";
                    System.out.println("each solution of " + t4);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Line class:

```
public class Line extends Button {


public Line(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void checkSubclass() { 
    // Disable the check that prevents sub-classing of SWT components 
} 

public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
    Line.this.setEnabled(false);
    Line.this.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
    String t4 = "move([[line(9,10,cpu),line(11,16,cpu),line(16,17,cpu),line(17,22,p1),line(5,6,p1),line(2,3,p1),line(1,2,p1)],cpu],4,X).";
    System.out.println("each solution of " + t4);
}

public void pc() {
    Line.this.setEnabled(false);
    Line.this.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
}
```

The error I get is:
Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use an array? Can you use an ArrayList instead? There are several ways to get around this that basically consist of the collection being declared final, but not its contents.

Comment: As an aside, if you were trying to make a 2D array, your code currently makes a 1D array of size 20 but only fills in the first 4 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference `i` in your mouse adapter anonymous class because its value changes. Instead use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        final Line line = new Line(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lines[i] = line;

        line.setBounds(100 + i * 35,54 + j * 13,32,11);

        line.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent e) {
                line.setEnabled(false);
                line.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));

                ... 
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here a `final Line line` creates a final instance of a line which can be referenced in the listener.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using a `final line`, could use `((Line)e.getSource())` to get MouseEvent parent.